# How to get the range of time

Tags: java, android, time

I'm trying to get the range of time from 8:00 am to 8:00 pm and 8:00 pm to 8:00 am, I'm trying to get schedules to display it in the recyclerview from firebase.

This is the code that I've structured.

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int ds = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    if(ds==0)
        AM_PM="am";
    else
        AM_PM="pm";

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+hour+":"+min+AM_PM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (hour >= 8 && AM_PM.matches("am") || hour >= 12 && AM_PM.matches("pm") || hour <= 7 && min <=59 && sec <=59  && AM_PM.matches("pm") ){
        fill_with_data_shift1();
    }else if (hour >= 20 && AM_PM.matches("pm") || hour >= 00 && AM_PM.matches("am")){
        fill_with_data_shift2();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: There are times that the codition doesnt meet.

Comment: It displays the shift even if it isn't meant to be there.

Comment: @AyushKhare Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints and see what is going wrong?

Comment: @AyushKhare like I should do it hour by hour and minutes??

Comment: Why do you check AM/PM when `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` is always 24 hours? [See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your code should be:

```
// between 8am and 8pm (not included)
if (hour >= 8 && hour < 20) {
    // Do something
} else { // the rest of the time
    // Do something else
}
```

Minutes, seconds and all the rest don't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Using the modern Java date & time API this comes quite naturally:

```
    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Manila"));

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String displayTime = currentTime.format(dtf).toLowerCase();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), displayTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (currentTime.isBefore(LocalTime.of(8, 0))
            || ! currentTime.isBefore(LocalTime.of(20, 0))) { // not-before means on or after
        fill_with_data_shift2();
    } else {
        fill_with_data_shift1();
    }
```

Since getting the local time is a time zone sensitive operation, think twice about the time zone you pass to `LocalTime.now()`. If you want to use the device’s time zone setting, pass `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

For Android you get the modern API in **ThreeTenABP**, see [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).